# anchor tag to send post data to another page

Tags: php, jquery, post, submit, anchor

I am making a **quiz system** (in php, javascript) in which there are four anchor tags,  representing four choices. In these anchor tags I want to use submit behaviour. I have searched **stackoverflow** and **googled** it, i have got how to send form using javascript. But the real difficulty is that I have to save the values of these tags which user clicked into database but I am not getting values by `$_POST` of the php in this case? how can I get the `POST` data in the next page which anchor tag clicked.

Kindly help me in this.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create one selector for all for of your anchor tags and then submit the code to a next page.

first we have your anchors as follows.

```
<a href="#" class="answer" data-answer-id="3">Answer 3</a>
<a href="#" class="answer" data-answer-id="4">Answer 4</a>
```

Then lets create a small form components that's hidden from the user interface but is there on the dom

```
<form style="display: none" action="nextpage.php" method="post" id='form'><input type="hidden" name="answer" /></form>
```

then in your jquery code you intercept the click from the anchor and set the values in the form and submit it.

```
$(".answer").click(function (e) {
    $("input[name=answer]").val($(this).data('answer-id'));
    $("#form").submit();
});
```